# How can I see what variables are defined in the window object with Chrome's developer tools?

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, google-chrome-devtools

I used to have an easy solution for this problem: open the developer tools console, start typing one or a few letters… and bam, chrome would autocomplete any variable name available in `window` (or in the `this` object when debugging). I mostly used this to see if something like `jQuery` is defined.
Since recently, Chrome's console has a new autocomplete feature that autocompletes previously typed statements. I can now no longer use my old work flow to find available variables.

I found that by typing `window.` first (note the period), you will sort of get the list of autocompleted variable names like how it was in older versions of Chrome, but it will also include previously evaluated statements starting with that.

Typing `window` and then pressing enter will print the window object; expanding it will reveal all defined variables and members, but I liked how the old way let you easily filter by typing the first few starting characters.

Comment: I am using Chrome Beta and can autocomplete like you described, which version are you using?

Comment: Stable channel, 64 bit, version: 49.0.2623.112 m

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the Developer Tools open (<kbd>F12</kbd>), go to settings (<kbd>F1</kbd>). Under "Console", uncheck "Autocomplete from history". Now you will get a list of autocompleted variable names like how it was in older versions of Chrome.

Typing `window` and then pressing enter, will print the window object; expanding it will also reveal all defined variables and members.

Answer (score 2):

[Switch to the beta channel of Chrome.](https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/beta.html)

Comment: Don't you think the new autocomplete functionality will eventually be added there as well?

Comment: It's still there together with the properties.

Answer (score 1):

I built a chrome extension called JS Digger which allows you to search for variable names and values defined in the window object.

JS Digger Link: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/js-digger/ndindkkcbpmfoinihohmhdhphgpiofbb?hl=en&authuser=3

Comment: Thank you! I've been having trouble locating values hidden behind things fancier than simple objects, and out of the dozens of scripts I tried this was the first solution for me